# new directory made from File not added

Tags: java, android, filesystems

Im trying to make a custom file system

im adding new directory by next code:

```
public String CreateFolder (String path,String name, String style){



        String fullPath_item=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        String final_path=fullPath_item+path+"/"+name;
        File theDir1 = new File(final_path);
        if (!theDir1.exists()){
            boolean check = theDir1.mkdirs();
            boolean check2=theDir1.mkdir();
            //openDirectory(final_path,123);;
            writeStringAsFile(final_path,"root.txt",style);            //System.out.println(theDir1.mkdir());
            //System.out.println(theDir1.mkdirs());
        }


        File theDir2 = new File(final_path+"/root.txt");
        if (theDir1.exists() & theDir2.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Folder exist: "+final_path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return final_path;

    }
```

upon `theDir1.exists() & theDir2.exists()` checker it says that both directory and root file are beign made.

extracting subderectories with

```
File directoryPath = new File(CurrentFolder);
            FileFilter textFilefilter = new FileFilter(){
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    boolean isFile = file.isFile();
                    if (isFile) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            };
            File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles(textFilefilter);
```

This code returns null, even if directories were made by previous code

I managed to have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Which mean i probably have permission to create directories.

I thought it is something about new directories were made and i need permission to access them, tried Intent with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT, but it throws exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 14260
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.GenerateWindow(MainActivity.java:1320)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:1612)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Spent whole night to figure out what is happening, tryied a lot of different solutions, but directory still does not create, or, by some reason, newly made directories are invisible.

Comment: Your error message says `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.GenerateWindow(MainActivity.java:1320)` but you've haven't included your `GenerateWindow` method in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: seems wrong. GenerateWIndow is added on MainActivity java. 100%. What about folders? They're still no adding.

Comment: You need to also test the directory for canRead() canWrite() and canExecute() before attempting to write into the folder. Also, use only one of mkDirs() not both or there will be a collision (although it does not show). If any of those tests fail , there are setReadable setWritable and setExecutable methods also in File class

Comment: If the directory exists then you should skip over the mkDirs() also.

Comment: ```
String fullPath_item=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+path;

        String final_path=fullPath_item+"/"+name;
        File theDir1 = new File(final_path);
        theDir1.setReadable(true);
        theDir1.setExecutable(true);
        theDir1.setWritable(true);
```
Does not help. Application still report that directory and root exist, but `File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles(textFilefilter);` still return null.

Interesting thing that init folders are created and shown correctly, but i cannot add new folders.

Comment: solved problem by using flat adress for item creation and absolute cacheDir() path in item reading.